# aws - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutMetricData operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run the Lambda function. How can this be fixed.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutMetricData 
operation: User: arn:aws:sts::12345678:assumed-role/someRole/role is not authorized 
to perform: cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allow `someRole` - the one assumed by the lambda function - to write metrics to cloudwatch. The policy should look like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["cloudwatch:PutMetricData"], # add more actions if needed
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT**
*Regarding OP comment about what should you use as resource instead of "*"*

PutMetricData has no resource-level permission, so it must be "*". If you are using namespaces, you can use a condition keys to limit access to your namespace.

As example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "cloudwatch:namespace": "MyNamespace"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what resource should i target instead of `*`

Comment: PutMetricData has no resource-level permission, so it must be "*". If you are using namespaces, you can use a condition keys to limit access to your namespace. See edits for example of such policy.